# Matlab lookuptable for variables

Tags: matlab, lookup, synthesizer

Hello I have been creating a matlab script of a Yamaha DX7 synth.
This for better understanding for mine synth(Nord modular G2 with DX7 emulator within).
The DX7 have 32 different algoritms. I have at this moment just the first [image: see figure algoritms]

the code i have is the following matlab code:

```
%% Feedback loop DX 7 Like
fs = 44100; f_b = 440; t = 0:1/44100:5; % f_b = Frequency basic
n = 5 * fs +1;

r = [1 1 1 1 1 1]; % ratio's for the different tones.
l = [1 1 1 .75 1 .5]; % Levels of amplitude 
feedback = 1; % how much go back in the system 
% 0 = 0%; 1 = @%; 2 = @%; 3 = @%; 4 = @%; 5 = @%; 6 = @%; 7 = @%
if feedback ==0
    fb = 0;
elseif feedback == 1;
    fb = 1^2;
elseif feedback == 2;
    fb = 2^2;
elseif feedback == 3;
    fb = 3^2;
elseif feedback == 4;
    fb = 4^2;   
elseif feedback == 5;
    fb = 5^2;  
elseif feedback == 6;
    fb = 6^2;
elseif feedback == 7;
    fb = 7^2;
else
    fb = 7^2;
end
%% DX7 stuff
% Operator 6
for k=1:n
    if k == 1;
        phif = 0;
    else
    phif = y6(1,k-1)*fb;
    end
    y6(1,k) = l(1,6) * sin (2*pi*r(1,6)*f_b*t(1,k)+phif);

end

y5 = l(1,5) * sin (2*pi*r(1,5)*f_b*t+y6);
y4 = l(1,4) * sin (2*pi*r(1,4)*f_b*t+y5);
y3 = l(1,3) * sin (2*pi*r(1,3)*f_b*t+y4);

y2 = l(1,2) * sin (2*pi*r(1,2)*f_b*t+0);
y1 = l(1,1) * sin (2*pi*r(1,1)*f_b*t+y2);

y = y3 + y1;
figure; plot(t,y4);xlim([0,0.5]);
```

The next step is creating a kind of lookuptable for getting rooting changes.
What i want is `y = A *sin(2*pi*f*t + phi)` and what the input of phi  comes from the lookuptable.
so for algoritm 2 i have the changes `phif = y2(1,k-1)*fb;`,`y2 = l(1,2) * sin (2*pi*r(1,2)*f_b*t+phif)` and `y6(1,k) = l(1,6) * sin (2*pi*r(1,6)*f_b*t(1,k)+0)`.

Edit:
I have 6 sine output signals y1 - y6 and I have 6 phase inputs of the signals phi1 - phi6. I have aslo a mix.

I want read out the routing from a lookup table. 
For example algoritm 7: `mix1 = y4 + y5` and `phi5 = y6`.
`phi5 = y6` is stored in a lookup table. and from the lookup table i need to import my variables

but i don't have any idea how i have to do this…

I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but maybe you're looking to make an array of anonymous functions? But as an aside, you could replace all those `elseif feedback...` lines with this: `fb = min(feedback, 7)^2`

Comment: thanks for `elseif` loop but is it not `fb = max(feedback, 7)^2` because 7 is the maximum number i want to have for feedback?
i have edit the last part maybe it's now better to understand

Comment: No it's `min`, you only want to revert to `7` when `feedback` is greater than `7`. If you use `max` then you'll get `7` for all values of `feedback` less than or equal to `7` otherwise you'll get `feedback` if it's larger. So you definitely want `min` and not `max`